# React Stripe Payment Create Customer and Order / Shipping Address etc

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, aws-lambda, stripe-payments

I created stripe payment page using gatsby react and aws lambda. But this code not create customer data like ( shipping address, email etc. )

Lamdba Code

```
const stripe = require("stripe")(process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY);

module.exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
  console.log("creating charge...");

  // Pull out the amount and id for the charge from the POST
  console.log(event);
  const requestData = JSON.parse(event.body);
  console.log(requestData);
  const amount = requestData.amount;
  const token = requestData.token.id;

  // Headers to prevent CORS issues
  const headers = {
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Content-Type"
  };

  return stripe.charges
    .create({
      // Create Stripe charge with token
      amount,
      source: token,
      currency: "usd",
      description: "Tshirt"
    })
    .then(charge => {
      // Success response
      console.log(charge);
      const response = {
        headers,
        statusCode: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify({
          message: `Charge processed!`,
          charge
        })
      };
      callback(null, response);
    })
    .catch(err => {
      // Error response
      console.log(err);
      const response = {
        headers,
        statusCode: 500,
        body: JSON.stringify({
          error: err.message
        })
      };
      callback(null, response);
    });
};
```

Gatsby Payment Code

Code is working , payment is working. but shipping details not working.

```
openStripeCheckout(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.setState({ disabled: true, buttonText: "WAITING..." });
    this.stripeHandler.open({
      name: "Demo Product",
      amount: amount,
      shippingAddress: true,
      billingAddress: true,
      description: "",
       token: (token, args) => {
        fetch(`AWS_LAMBDA_URL`, {
          method: "POST",
          body: JSON.stringify({
            token,
            args,
            amount,
          }),
          headers: new Headers({
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
          }),
        })
          .then(res => {
            console.log("Transaction processed successfully");
            this.resetButton();
            this.setState({ paymentMessage: "Payment Successful!" });
            return res.json();
          })
          .catch(error => {
            console.error("Error:", error);
            this.setState({ paymentMessage: "Payment Failed" });
          });
      },
    });
  }
```

I want to see customer data , shipping address etc.

Thanks for helping.

Comment: In your backend you seem to be pulling out the amount and token id, but not the shipping data. When you `console.log(requestData);` do you see the content of `args` (the shipping data) entered on your front end? You can pull the email from `requestData.token.email` https://stripe.com/docs/checkout#required

Comment: @duck thanks for answer. but i dont know how can i do this ? can u write example code ?

Answer (score 1):

The billing and shipping address are both available in the `args`-argument of the token callback you're collecting.

https://jsfiddle.net/qh7g9f8w/

```
var handler = StripeCheckout.configure({
  key: 'pk_test_xxx',
  locale: 'auto',
  token: function(token, args) {

    // Print the token response
    $('#tokenResponse').html(JSON.stringify(token, null, '\t'));

    // There will only be args returned if you include shipping address in your config
    $('#argsResponse').html(JSON.stringify(args, null, '\t'));

  }
});
```